# Rails 4: Where does .codeclimate.yml go in my public Git project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, code-climate

I see this at codeclimate.com and I want it to go away. What should I do?

[image]

I [enabled the Code Climate platform](http://docs.codeclimate.com/article/300-the-codeclimate-platform#ready) and here is where I created my .codeclimate.yml, using the default .yml file [Code Climate provides](http://docs.codeclimate.com/article/289-configuring-your-repository-via-codeclimate-yml#platform).

[image]

[Code Climate docs](http://docs.codeclimate.com/article/289-configuring-your-repository-via-codeclimate-yml#platform) say...

> Add a brand new .codeclimate.yml to the root of your default branch
>   (replace any existing Code Climate config file).

I am probably misunderstanding what Code Climate means by "root of your default branch."

> **Default branch** is defined as: Since Git repositories can contain multiple branches, Code Climate needs to know which the branch to
>   focus on. We refer to this branch as the default." [How do I set my
>   default branch?](http://docs.codeclimate.com/article/151-glossary-default-branch) "When adding a private GitHub repository (without
>   entering a URI), or when adding an open source GitHub repository, your
>   default Code Climate branch will always be set to your default Github
>   branch...For all other situations, you'll be prompted to set the
>   default branch...Note: It is currently not possible to change your
>   default branch after adding a repository to Code Climate. In addition,
>   once a repository has been added to Code Climate, changing the default
>   branch in GitHub will not change the default branch in Code Climate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Climate submitted a pull request with the following changes and the warning message went away upon merging.

(fwiw, excellent and prompt customer service)

[image: Code Climate tweaks]